# rendering multiples of the same radio buttons error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```html
<%= simple_form_for :appointment, url: delete_admin_appointment_path(appointment) do |f| %>
```

I have a rails application , where on my appointments index table, i have the option to cancel an appointment (in the form of a modal). However im using radio buttons on the modal. This works fine for the very first appointment, but if I try to click on any other radio buttons for the other appointments, they arent clickable because they are actually changing the radio buttons on the first appointment instead. So i basically need to make each modals radio buttons unique to that modal so they dont change any others, but im not sure how. thanks

```html
 <div class="modal-flex">
          <%= f.radio_button :delete_appointment, :true %>
          <%= f.label :delete_appointment_true, "Yes", class: "modal-options cancel" %>
     
          <%= f.radio_button :delete_appointment, :false %>
          <%= f.label :delete_appointment_false, "No", class: "modal-options cancel" %>
          
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `f` seems to me that you are constantly updating the first record?
Are you looping through your appointments and then making the forms? Please just give a bit more details.

Comment: Yes, the first record is always being updated. And yes, i'm iterating through all the appointments and then rendering the form within the iteration.

Comment: @b.herring please give me a bit more details, where is your submit button, what is equal to. For modal, you need to make full modal for every instance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you correct it to this:

```
<div class="modal-flex">
  <%= f.radio_button :delete_appointment, true %>
  <%= f.label :delete_appointment, "Yes", class: "modal-options cancel" %>

  <%= f.radio_button :delete_appointment, false %>
  <%= f.label :delete_appointment, "No", class: "modal-options cancel" %>
</div>
```

I hope this might solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, but this is breaking it even more, as now the radio buttons and the labels dont match.